# Q.E.D., C.Q.F.D. ou c.q.f.d

Tags: science, acronymes

Peut-on employer de nos jours, par exemple dans des polycopiés (maths, physique, etc.), l'acronyme *Q.E.D.* pour signaler la fin d'une preuve ?

Est-ce plus fréquent l'emploi de la version francisée *C.Q.F.D.* ?

En plus, j'ai rencontré les variantes « C.Q.F.D. » et « c.q.f.d. » . Laquelle est la correcte ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu Q.E.D., ce sera peut-être pas le cas du lecteur mais tu risques quand même de ne pas te faire comprendre

Comment: Quand j’étais en fac de physique l'emploi de CQFD était très répandu dans les polycopiés. Cependant je n'ai jamais vu QED.

Comment: Après quelques recherches, il semble que les dictionnaires ne soient pas d'accord sur la casse de CQFD, mais que le QED soient généralement laissé de côté en francais quoi qu'il en soit. Cela dit il semble que l'on tende à ne plus utiliser CQFD non plus, au profit de symboles comme un rectangle plein, ou un rectangle blanc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'usage de QED et de CQFD, n'est pas des plus répandu. Cela dit, nombreux sont les cours de mathématiques données aux étudiants dans les facs ou les classes préparatoires, dans lesquelles les démonstrations finissent par CQFD. Dans les mileux scientifiques, l'usage de QED est assez anecdotique, je parle en connaissance de cause. Celà dit, QED bien que désuet est tout à fait possible d'usage, personnellement je le préfère si la démonstration est longue et fastidieuse. J'ajouterai que QED ajoute un côté érudit par celui qui l'emploie, étant donné que l'apprentissage du latin de nos jours est quasiment inexistant. Il est certainement possible de trouver QED dans d'anciens livres de mathématiques, à l'époque pour les scientifiques apprenaient encore le latin et le grec.

On trouve aussi fréquemment, l'utilisation de CQFD ou de cqfd (exactement le même sens) à la fin de quelques articles journalistiques.

Et comme précisé dans les commentaires, souvent l'usage de symbole, comme un carré par exemple fait office de CQFD.